# A place to obtain what's left

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, lateral-thinking

> Put away your expectations this riddle is rough
>   Are lost then found ale, mine now to obtain this is tough
>
> Oh no a, set of eyes that never rest
>   Gone from the start then ripped from my chest
>
> Are never in, what endures time the bluff
>   Without tea protests when not up to snuff
>
> No end so why, a tale of one in the west
>   Resulting in a place to obtain what's left

What am I?

**Hint #1**

> The first and last lines allude to the word, while the others hint to transformed versions of the word.

**Hint #2**

> Look to the first portions of the lines for instructions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Are you...**

> A store?

**Put away your expectations this riddle is rough**

> Not really sure about this one.

**Are lost then found ale, mine now to obtain this is tough**

> Remove the "r" and replace it with "ale"? Not quite sure on this one either.

**Oh no a, set of eyes that never rest**

> Remove the "o", replace with "a": STARE

**Gone from the start then ripped from my chest**

> Remove the first letter: TORE (tore is a synonym for ripped)

**Are never in, what endures time the bluff**

> Remove the "r", replace with "n": STONE (stone shores endure the ocean's "bluff")

**Without tea protests when not up to snuff**

> Remove the "t": SORE (body protests/is sore when not feeling well)

**No end so why, a tale of one in the west**

> Remove the last letter, replace with "y": STORY (stories tell tales)

**Resulting in a place to obtain what's left**

> STORE (where you can get what they have left on the shelves)

Comment: I think the ale is just an L, so that "mine now!" fits. And store also means to put away.

Comment: That 's right! Some of the lines aren't interpreted fully/quite the way I had in mind, so think a little more on it and when you update your answer, I'll mark it as correct. Nice work though! @MOehm You're right too ;)

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Wanna give this the tick, then?

Comment: @feelinferrety I was going to wait until they updated... but since they haven't and might not come back, sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

Possible answers to lines 3 and 4:

**Oh no a, set of eyes that never rest**

> stare

**Gone from the start then ripped from my chest**

> tear. Removed the start of the previous word. This leaves us with tear from stare.

Comment: Your first guess is correct and the second one is close. Nice job!